# When is it fair to purposefully cause undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, libraries, undefined-behavior, contract

The standard library habitually allows for undefined behaviour if you break any requirements on template types, give erroneous function arguments, or any other breach of contract. Is it considered a good practise to allow this in user libraries? When is it fair to do so?

Consider writing an `operator[]` for a container:

```
template <typename t>
T& container<T>::operator[](int i)
{
  return internal_array[i];
}
```

If `i` indexes outside the bounds of the `internal_array`, we hit undefined behaviour. Should we allow this to happen or do bounds checking and throw an exception?

Another example is a function that takes an `int` argument but only allows a restricted domain:

```
int foo(int x)
{
  if (x > 0 && x <= 10) {
    return x;
  }
}
```

If `x` is not within the domain, execution will reach the end of the function without a `return` statement - this gives undefined behaviour.

Should a library developer feel bad for allowing this or not?

Comment: Might be a better fit for programmers, I don't know.

Comment: Personally: If it's easy to give better diagnostics in the debug build (i.e. using asserts or something) I always go for it. Implementations of the standard library at least sometimes follow similar guidelines: `[]` often does bounds checking in debug builds. **But** there's never any reason to cause undefined behavior if you can avoid it at no additional runtime cost - if you're already doing the bounds checking give a good diagnostic.

Comment: @chris Maybe. I wasn't sure.

Comment: If its a libraries then you have to indicate to the user of the library to check the input themselves.

Comment: It depends on the problem. I wouldn't add runtime checks to protect users who don't read documentation or can't be bothered with ensuring that they don't use erroneous data; that just slows everything down.

Comment: Most programs would run just fine, performance-wise, if you added checks for everything. The reason libraries tend to default to just having no checks is that *you can add checks on top*; it's much harder to remove checks.

Comment: This question should be reopened. This is clearly a design decision that needs to be taken while programming, and thus is clearly on-topic on a programming Q&A.

Comment: The library developer is not *causing* the UB; it's the user who steps outside the contract offered by the library. It is often too expensive to eliminate all UB from interfaces. Of course, the library should offer a clear and precise contract: which exception guarantees holds for which values of input, which inputs are validated, etc. But assuming that's in place (as it is for e.g. the integer shift `operator<<` and the container `operator[]`), the user is on his own. Caveat emptor. Note, that this does not apply to library code that itself contains UB, e.g. mulithreaded code with races.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I agree that there is a valid question here provided it is worded correctly. As it stands, it is nonsensical: nobody ever allows undefined behavior anywhere. The standard allows implementors to *not* defined behavior in many circumstances. All API writers are able to do the same thing and this question asks when that is appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

> When is it fair to purposefully cause undefined behaviour?

Assuming you're asking this from the point of view of a library implementer: whenever you warn your client that failing to comply with the pre-conditions of a given function causes Undefined Behavior, and your client breaks those pre-conditions.

The C++11 Standard Library defines a lot of such functions: just think of the subscript operator for sequence collections.

If you're asking this from the viewpoint of an application programmer, on the other hand, the answer is of course "never", *unless* you are writing non-portable code that relies on some *documented* extension of your compiler and/or on some functionality of your Operating System (but then it's arguable whether you are still "talking C++").

> Should a library developer feel bad for allowing this or not?

If that was the case, mr. Stepanov should feel *horrible* by now. No, it is not bad, it just depends on whether your library is designed for maximum efficiency or for maximum safety - with a lot of nuances in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

It all boils down to documentation.

Intuitively you wouldn't expect `[]` to do any bound checking, but you could also provide an `at` method to your container that throws an exception (yay, just like the folks that write the `std`). Of course you could throw an exception, but document this behavior.

The second is fair-play as well as long as you clearly document that the behavior is undefined if the function is called with the bad arguments **and** you have a good reason to do so (red on). If you're designing a performance-critical library, you don't want the overhead of checking input. If not, throw an exception.

Comment: Personally I would consider a library that doesn't do simple bounds checking in a debug build (to stay with the example), badly designed. E.g. every `std` implementation I know has an assertion doing the bounds checking in `[]` for vectors - I don't even want to estimate how many off-by-1 bugs were found thanks to this.